# Doing a bar of buttons with CSS: problems with display:block, paddings and <li />s

Tags: css

I'm doing a horizontal bar of buttons with CSS so I can have something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Button 1  | Button 2   | Button 3    | Button 4   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

But I don't understand why my button text is bigger than the `<li />`that contains that `<a />`. I've done a jsfiddle example to show what happens, you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7m4rE/ .

How I can solve this problem? I'm only supporting IE9+ and last Chrome, FF, Opera.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set an explicit height on either your `li` or your `a`. Rather, let your padding and margin on the `a` determine how tall the elements will be.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m4rE/1/